# Referencing Classes from Different Targets in xCode for iPhone Unit Testing

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing, ios

I am trying to unit test my iPhone application. I have created a new target and called it "LogicTests". But now I need to use a class called "Spaceship" inside the test. How can I do that?

UPDATE 1:

I made the `Spaceship.m` available to the unit testing target and that particular error was gone. Now I have different problem. The `Spaceship.m` file reference to the Cocos2d library. How can I add a reference to the Cocos2d library in the unit testing target. I tried right clicking the Link binary with libraries option and then adding the cocos2d framework but it gave me 153 errors or something.

Answer (score 2):

To include it in that target, click on `Spaceship.m`, get the file's Info (Command-I), and make sure "LogicTests" is checked under the Target tab.

Beyond that, make sure you add

```
#import "Spaceship.h"
```

To the top of the particular test class. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4 you press: Alt-Command-1 and then check that "LogicTests" is checked under the Target Membership tab.